# Lazy loading occurring for some reason when DeferredLoadingEnabled is false

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, lazy-loading

I'm using `LinqToSql` and in order to **prevent** lazy loading each datacontext has this setting:

```
DeferredLoadingEnabled = false
```

Now, I'm using a data context that add's 3 sub tables as a loadoption. 
Something like:

```
EntitiesDataContext dc = new EntitiesDataContext(connectionString);
dc.DeferredLoadingEnabled = false;
LoadOptions lo = new LoadOptions();
lo.LoadWith<Entity1>(e => e.Entity2);
lo.LoadWith<Entity1>(e => e.Entity3);
lo.LoadWith<Entity1>(e => e.Entity4);
dc.Loadoptions = lo;
```

I perform a simple select on the `Entity1` table and return an `IQueryable<Entity1>`.

```
IQueryable<Entity1> myQuery = GetMyEntity1Collection();
```

And then I have a piece of code which selects specific things from `Entity1` into an anonymous object and then builds a slim `Entity1` with relevant properties- This is done to **increase performance** since `Entity1` has large xml columns that I prefer not to load:

```
myQuery.Select(item => 
    new
    {
       A = item.A,
       B = item.B,
       ....
       Entity15 = item.Entity15
    }).ForEach(item => 
    new Entity1
    {
       A = item.A,
       B = item.B,
       ....
       Entity15 = item.Entity15
    })
);
```

For the record, the `ForEach` is a custom extension method that looks like this:

```
   public static void ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source, Action<T> action)
   {
        foreach (var item in source)
        {
           action(item);
        }
    }
```

My problem:

`Entity15` is a sub table that has a foreign key to `Entity1`.
It is **not** loaded as a loadoption as you can see and I don't want it to be loaded.
When I run this I see multiple queries in my sql profiler that actually load `Entity15` each time(looks like a lazy load to me).

Now I have no idea why this happens. I think it has something to do with the anonymous object that is created but I really don't know.

I've enter the method in debug mode, performed a `ToList`(executed the `IQueryable`) and checked `Entity15`, the `HasLoadedOrAssignedValues` was **false** exactly like I **wanted**, but when I put a break point inside the `ForEach` I see it as **true**. 
Does anybody have any idea about this one?

Comment: Why you don't use Entity Framework?

Comment: @abatishchev - It's all about priorities :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found an answer:

First of all I found out LinqToSql has problems with loading multiple one to many tables as you can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11869659/linq-to-sql-multiple-trips-to-the-database) and [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/zeeshanhirani/constraints-with-loadwith-when-loading-multiple-1-n-relationships).

When I enumerated the queryable it simply ignored the loadwith's and that's why a ToList() in debug mode gave different result than during enumeration.