# Linq to SQL prefetching multiple tables not working

Tags: linq-to-sql

I am trying to prefetch some related tables using Linq to SQL but only one table is being prefetched.

My code looks like this...

```
using (EVTDataContext db = new EVTDataContext(Config.ConnString))
{
    DataLoadOptions loadOptions = new DataLoadOptions();
    loadOptions.LoadWith<EVT_tbEventVersion>(c => c.EVT_tbRegistrations);
    loadOptions.LoadWith<EVT_tbEventVersion>(c => c.EVT_tbSubEvents);
    db.LoadOptions = loadOptions;

    var q = ...
```

EVT_tbRegistrations and EVT_tbSubEvents are both associated with EVT_tbEventVersion. If I use either of the LoadWidth line son their own they each work, but if I use both then only one works.

How can I make Linq to SQL prefetch both tables?

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644576/linq2sql-eager-load-with-multiple-dataloadoptions

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that when searching for a solution. Seems like Linq to SQL can't be relied upon to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems Linq to SQL can only join a single one-to-many relationship from each table. If you try to specify more than one to preload it picks which one to preload and which others to leave deferred (ignoring LoadWith).

Answer was found at [Linq2SQl eager load with multiple DataLoadOptions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/644576/linq2sql-eager-load-with-multiple-dataloadoptions)

Answer (score -1):

I have no experience with what you are doing .. but after checking MSDN here [How to: Retrieve Many Objects At Once (LINQ to SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Bb386917%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) I can see differences between your code and the MS example.  Most notably:

```
DataLoadOptions ds = new DataLoadOptions();
ds.LoadWith<Customer>(c => c.Orders);
ds.LoadWith<Order>(o => o.OrderDetails);
db.LoadOptions = ds;
```

Where the specify a different `<T>` for each prefetch.

Comment: Thats pretty much the same as what I am doing except in that example Order Details is related to Orders which is related to Customers. In my code both tbRegistrations and tbSubEvents are both directly related to tbEventVersion.

Comment: Like I said .. I don't know what I am doing .. so maybe I should have just kept my fingers off the keyboard.