# Extreme performance issue in MVC4 due to poorly designed business and database layers

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

**Second update 24.10.2013**

I've narrowed this problem down to my database layer. Apparently it's a performance issue with LINQ2SQL. Imagine loading 10 entities in a single query and then adding logic to retrieve child entities for those 10 main entities. For performance tuning you would like to execute that data retrieval in one single query, but L2S does this in a total of 11 queries:

- One query to retrieve the 10 main entities
- Ten queries to retrieve *n* amount of child entities for each main entity

Various blogs and articles online have confirmed my findings, although those articles are a couple of years old, some dating back as far as to 2007. The articles I've found state that Entity Framework is a possible solution to this, as EF supports the expected behaviour which L2S does not support. Sad but true, it seems I will have to re-program my database layer.

**First update 24.10.2013**

I have narrowed this problem further down with the help of ANTS Profiler. There seems to be a problem in my business logic and general design. I've discovered a tendency where objects are being created way too many times rather than just using the already created version. I am doing a major overhaul and optimizing the code to see if this will improve the performance of the website as experienced by the end-user.

**The question**

I'm experiencing serious performance issues while rendering MVC views. Rendering a view with just two lines of text takes 3.75 seconds according to browser consoles, tested in Chrome and Internet Explorer by accessing /Innhold/Mangler

The application is running in a production environment built in Release mode with  in Web.config

What on Earth is the reason for this severe performance issue? I'm starting to run out of ideas here.

Code is attached below.

I've got the following view called "Feil":

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Feil";
    Layout = "";
}

<h2>Feil</h2>
<pre>@ViewBag.Exception</pre>
```

I've got the following action called "Mangler" in the controller "Innhold":

```
public ActionResult Mangler()
{
    ViewBag.Exception = "Det er ikke konfigurert noen nettside for denne lenken.";
    ViewBag.Title = "404";
    ViewBag.WebsiteID = 0;

    return View("~/Views/Shared/Feil.cshtml");
}
```

I've cleared and added the only ViewEngine I need aswell as specified the only file extension I need in Application_Start() in Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
    FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);

    ViewEngines.Engines.Clear();
    ViewEngines.Engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine() { FileExtensions = new string[] { "cshtml" } });
}
```

Comment: You would like to try removing ViewBag.Exception from both view and controller?

Comment: Running the app from Visual Studio is also much slower because of all the debugging components that are preloaded.

Comment: @MillerKoijam I tried, no notable change.

Comment: @RealityDysfunction The application is running in a production environment with debugging disabled.

Comment: @rsbarro This is for every page view.

Comment: Have you verified that the application is not restarting for some reason after every page view?

Comment: @rsbarro I have indeed. It is not restarting.

Comment: Have you tried profiling with NewRelic (that's an easy way to get traces, even in DEV)? =]

Comment: @rsbarro That is something I have not tried. I'll take a look at it.

Comment: You may want to look at Glimpse (see http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IfYoureNotUsingGlimpseWithASPNETForDebuggingAndProfilingYoureMissingOut.aspx and http://getglimpse.com/) to see where the execution time is being taken - it's excellent, free and open source.

Comment: Are you sure MVC is the one to blame? Could it be possible that you're experiencing some network issues or that the server is slow for some reasons (other services consuming too much cpu cycles and so on...)?

Comment: @AirL I am monitoring the server closely, there are no abnormalities in regard to CPU, RAM or network usage. Loading normal HTML or txt files takes 10-30ms.

Comment: @Maritim i thing that glimpse from nuget would be one issue, Are you running on local pc or on server? Is your db on same location (server /pc). Have you enabled trace in webconfig? Have you created simple one page application and tried it to run => does it result with same issues? Does your web.config changes while your application is running?

Comment: The 1:N problem you've described is often encountered with Lazy loading. You should specify eager loading of the child entities along with the parent using [LoadWith](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/644576/linq2sql-eager-load-with-multiple-dataloadoptions) e.g. `options.LoadWith<Parent>(p => p.ChildEntities);`

Comment: @StuartLC I am currently looking into that. Do you perhaps have a code example to show how to parse the result into a parent object with underlying child objects?

Comment: @cpoDesign This is running in a production environment with the DB server on another W2K8 server in the same LAN. The web.config does not change during execution.

Comment: @Maritim if the child FK to the parent table is set up, and both tables have been pulled into the Linq2Sql model, then L2SQL should do the 'parsing' all by itself. Lazy loading is the default behavior, hence the suggestion to use `LoadsWith` on this screen (and possibly elsewhere).

Comment: @Maritim what is the flow.. what parts are hit? have you added sql profiler on the call? and see what is the query executed => can this be improoved?

Comment: @cpoDesign I've narrowed it down to query improval, and that's what I'm currently working on.

Comment: @Maritim did you tryied to hook up glimplse? its excellent tool

Comment: http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2007/12/02/linq-to-sql-lazy-and-eager-loading-hiccups/

You probably would need to understand things like LINQ 2 SQL before using them. Life is not as easy as Microsoft show us in their demos ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally solved this issue!

In the end this performance issue boiled down to a poorly designed business layer and database layer.

I used ANTS Profiler to narrow down the problematic methods and saw that constructors that should only be hit 1 time during the lifecycle of the application were being hit 36 times for each request. I also detected lots of other SQL queries generated by LINQ2SQL that required optimization, aswell as unneeded calls to the database.

I eliminated a lot of LINQ queries making database calls, optimized the remaining calls, stored object states which were intended to be re-used and did a lot of general optimization in my business layer and database layer.

I am now experiencing normal response times and page loads measuring as low as 170ms. The reason for this occurring also with simple views like the example in my original question is because I have a custom base controller which uses the database to retrieve some data before a view can be generated.

**Conclusion**

Poorly designed code in need of optimization made my web application sluggish and slow to respond.

**Result**

A thorough optimization implemented over the last 48 hours has resulted in a major performance boost and everything is now performing as expected. Mission accomplished!

Comment: Great job, thnx for sharing your result. What was cause of the 36 hits to constructor?

Comment: @cpoDesign The cause of the 36 hits was that I re-constructed the object in 36 different places rather than just storing it in the Application object in the current HttpContext, to enable my application to just inject it from the Application object whenever needed. I only needed to create it once, which made that solution viable in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem lies in compilation time. When the application first starts it needs to compile, so that it can run much faster when in use.

Look into this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13794580/mvc-asp-net-startup-time-revisited

Comment: If this was the case then subsequent calls would not be as slow, but they are, so this doesn't seem very plausible.. :(